# Join two pandas series by values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, merge

I have two very large series that contain only join keys.  Without using the index (meaningless in this case) I want to left join one series to another by the values in the most efficient way possible.

Right now, I add a column of 1's just so I can use `pd.merge` with a left join just so I can identify whether each key in `left` also exists in right.

I'm sure I can do this without creating the two unused columns but `pd.concat` seems to want to use indices for the join.  **Is there a way to left two series on values and is there a faster numpy version of this?**

For example:

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3])
b = pd.Series([1,3,6])
```

I want to return an array or Series that tells me if each value in `a` is in b in the most efficient way possible.

```
 [True, False, True]
```

Comment: Can you add samples?

Comment: Example values are up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
c = a.isin(b)
```

that returns:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

or if you want an array you can just:

```
c.values
```

that returns:

```
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Nice!  Does this scale well?  I have two 20MM record series...